# Разное выполнение одного и того же скрипта PHP

Tags: php, циклы, константа

Ребят, создал алгоритм для обработок строк, а он отказывается работать на сайте.

1. Рисунок 1 (Неправильная обработка строки)
2. Рисунок 2 (Правильное отображение)

[image: Выполнение кода на сайте][image: Выполнение кода на локальном хосте]

```
$strings = explode(PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL, $data['text_translate']);

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $a = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);
    var_dump($a);
}
```

Строка приходит в таком виде

```
Hello
Привет

Hello
Привет
```

Почему так всё выполняется? И как это исправить?

Comment: т.е. на сайте он работает то нормально то нет????

Comment: На сайте он работает так как показано на рисунке 1.То есть создаёт один массив, и там всё "съедает". А на локальном хосте он работает исправно. И я не понимаю почему так.

Comment: @PetrCool попробуйте так: `$strings = explode("\r\n", $data['text_translate']);`

Comment: Я конечно не гуру PHP но по моему это из-за операционных систем так как PHP_EOL  разными операционными системами воспринимается разно.

Comment: Посмотрел настройки php? Вдруг у тебя Php_eol по разному определенно.

Comment: @Самвел вы просто зверь! Спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: @petrCool ?????

Comment: @Самвел Да заработало наконец, ночь не спал в поисках решения.

Comment: @PetrCool ну поздравляю)

Comment: @PetrCool что заработало? То что я привёл в пример?

Comment: @Эдуард ой, перепутал, спасибо вам большое. (Бессонная ночь)